# How can i copy files between my local pc and an opened remote desktop from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-transfer, remote-desktop

I have opened a remote desktop connection to a windows server that has no interface apart from command line window.

How can i transfer a file from my local pc to that remote server? (either by sending from my local pc to the remote or getting by my remote from my local)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From remote session:** `Copy location.extension destination.extension`

**f.e.** `Copy c:\file.jpg m:\jpg`

**From the host:** `Copy destination.extension location.extension`

**f.e.** `Copy \\remote\c$\file.jpg C:\file.jpg`